# Which Parameters should be reported in a multiple linear regression model in accordance with APA guidelines?

Tags: apa-style, regression

I have conducted a multiple linear regression analysis in R, standardising the values of the predictors prior to analysis. The R output:R default outputprovides information on the coefficient estimate, the standard error, the t values, the p value, the residual standard error, the df's, the F value and the respective t value, the R square and the adjusted R square. The default APA regression table (apa.reg.table) function: APA regression tableprovides the b and respective CI, beta and respective CI, rs square and respective CI, r and R square. I now wonder which of these values I should include in my table and in the text to be best comprehensible while parsimonious.

Thanks in advance!

[image: R Studio OAPAutput]